# Boost log wildcards for log filename

Tags: boost-log

How can I customize the log file name adding the process id into it?

```
logging::add_file_log
    (
        keywords::file_name = "sample<PID????>_%N.log",                                        1
        keywords::rotation_size = 10 * 1024 * 1024,                                   2
        keywords::time_based_rotation = sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0), 3
        keywords::format = "[%TimeStamp%]: %Message%"                                 4
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Er... my mistake. I was trying to define a filename like "sample_%N%.log". After I sent the question here, I figured out that the wildcard %N was wrong as you can see.

Sorry guys